# Multiple Update

Tags: sql, mysql

I'm trying to update two query's in my php script but i can't get it to work. The code is:

UPDATE
table
SET price = '14.50'
WHERE
type LIKE 'finger', 'Knuckle'
AND
quantity <=50;

Okay, ive fixed the WHERE clause but i don't understand what i need to change with the '14.50' part which is now picking up an error?

Comment: LIKE is equivalent to "=" unless you put a wildcard somewhere.

Comment: It generally acts the same as =, except that = ignores trailing whitespace for VARCHAR and CHAR types, and = performs transformations according to character collation (so "ae" is equal to "ä"), whereas LIKE doesn't.  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html  For the purpose given in this questions, however, it is safe to treat them equivalently.

Answer (score 4):

```
UPDATE table SET price = '14.50'
WHERE type IN('finger', 'Knuckle') AND quantity <=50;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE table SET price = '14.50' WHERE (type LIKE 'finger' OR type LIKE 'Knuckle') AND quantity <=50;
```

Answer (score 0):

you may also want

```
update table set price = '14.50'
where (type like '%finger%' or type like '%knuckle%')
and quantity <= 50
```

This will match any strings in which  finger or knuckle are contained.